# php post method not working right

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="TakeTwo.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="trail" placeholder="Enter Test Here">
   <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

   $k = $_POST['trial'];

   echo $k;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

for some reason it gives me a error that says this:

> Notice: Undefined index: trial in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\KyleLongrich.com\TakeTwo.php on line 18

Any help would be awesome. Also line 18 is referring to to `echo $k`;

Comment: If you pass action="" then it will post data to current page, in your case it is POST data to the file name "TakeTwo.php"

Comment: remove the form action="taketwo.php" since php function is in the same file

Comment: I Tired that and it gave me the same error

Comment: Try the code `<input type="text" name="trial" placeholder="Enter Test Here"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">` and remove action from form tag `action=""`

Answer (score 2):

Spelling mistake (Trail instead of trial). Check this.

```
<html>  
<form action="TakeTwo.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="trail" placeholder="Enter Test Here">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">


<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

$k = $_POST['trail'];

echo $k;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have spell mistake for `trial` in your form.

Replace this :

```
<input type="text" name="trail" placeholder="Enter Test Here">
```

With this :

```
<input type="text" name="trial" placeholder="Enter Test Here">
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
  action = "TakeTwo.php" change to <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>
```

2.

```
  if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) to 
  if (!empty($_POST))
```

This will work well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **spelling error**.

Replace this

```
<input type="text" name="trail" placeholder="Enter Test Here">
```

By this

```
<input type="text" name="trial" placeholder="Enter Test Here">
```